# Buddypress Notifications

Tags: wordpress, notifications, buddypress

I’m working on a wordpress website, and using Buddypress. I wanted to add posts notifications and it worked fine, except when I tried to filter them. First you need to know how I want to filter them.
– I’ve a profile field named ‘Field’ which is a dropdown list with 5 options.
– I have also 5 post categories with the exact names of the ‘Field’ values.
– When a post is added, If it has (e.g. A,B,C) categories I want a notification for every user who has his ‘Field’ value is equal to A,B or C.

Here is my code:

```
foreach ($users as  $user) {
  $acc_type = xprofile_get_field_data('Field', $user->ID);
    if (in_category($acc_type,$post_id)) {
      bp_notifications_add_notification( array(
        'user_id'           => $user->ID,
        'item_id'           => $post_id,
        'component_name'    => 'custom',
        'component_action'  => 'custom_action',
        'date_notified'     => bp_core_current_time(),
        'is_new'            => 1,
      ) 
      );  
    }  
}
```